# Op-amp comparator circuit design for high/low voltage measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-electronics, comparator

I want to make a circuit to measure the voltage from (0 ~12 V), which can have two op-amps as comparator to give the output positive, when the voltage goes from 8 V to 12 V and give output negative when the voltage goes from 0 V to 4 V. The reference voltage should be 6 V (+/-2 V). Please suggest me the basic circuit using two op-amps.

- Input voltage: 0 to 12 V
- Reference voltage: V
- Higher limit: 8 V
- Lower limit: 4 V

This means, when I increase the input voltage from 6 V, it should not show any change until it crosses 8 V and when it's more than 8 V, it should show HIGH VOLTAGE.

Similarly, like when I down the input voltage from 6 V, it should not show any change in output until it crosses 4 V and when it's lower than 4 V, it should show LOW VOLTAGE.

---

*Table 1. Function table for OP to edit.*

```
V_IN        V_OUT
----------- ----------
0 - 4 V     Negative
4 - 8 V     0 V
8 - 12 V    Positive
```

---

[image: Please Refer This Cicuit]

Please refer this circuit and suggest me the corrections, if any.

Comment: Your deleted schematic shows an AC input. Is this correct? If so, does "4 volts" mean mean pk-pk, RMS, or average rectified? Or something else? And how much accuracy do you need? How many power supplies are you allowed for the op amps? You show a single 12 supply. Is +/- 12 allowed? What accuracy is required?

Comment: Hi, I just added the circuit. please check that.

Comment: @Emlinux: I've fixed the formatting in your question. Note 'V' for volt. (Capitals matter.) You can often save a lot of words with a table to define operation. I've added one for you with my understanding of your requirements. Please review and edit to fix any errors. You seem to be requiring a negative voltage output but your schematic shows a positive-only supply. Where is the negative voltage supposed to come from?

Comment: My comment copied from your deleted "answer": Note that you could make your schematic a lot more readable by using ground symbols close to each grounded point, eliminate all the ground wiring and the same with the V+ connections. Try and eliminate kinks in wiring such as above R4 and the loop under D1.

Comment: Your circuit runs off a single +12 supply. How do you expect to get a negative output (per your table)?

Comment: Why not create a very simpler comparator?.I have posted in this forum how to make 1 comparator using 1 MOSFET. See this:https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511889/comparator-simple-build

Answer (score 1):

What you talking about is a [Schmitt trigger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)

You may just pick one as an ic or turn an op amp into Schmitt trigger using positive feedback and then scale input using voltage divider

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following document:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf

Also, I am not quite sure, why you need two opamps to do the job. Why not just use one comparator?

Comment: Thanks Saqib. I am attaching here with my design, please refer it let me know your suggestions please.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any attachment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [window comparator](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa221a/sboa221a.pdf?ts=1664282839163&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), which is *basically* what your schematic is. However, yours is a modified version of the one blow. Information on these is readily available on the Web. For your particular application, you might need to work out appropriate voltage dividers.
For instance:

[image: Window Comparator] ([Source](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html))

Where, as you can see, the calculations are pretty straightforward.

Based on the thresholds that you need, you must have symmetric power supplies feeding the OPAMPS for an optimal response. This way, you can easily drive your output into (+) and (-) saturation.

A neat technique to create such symmetric voltages is the following, as proposed by Elliot Sound Projects:
[image: Symmetric Voltages from a single 9V batt] ([Source](https://sound-au.com/project154.htm))

EDIT: [Another](https://sound-au.com/articles/comparators.htm#s6) fantastic resource from Elliot Sound