# Comparator simple build

Tags: mosfet, comparator

So I was trying to learn about what comparators do and I did. They compare 2 voltages and if the voltage at the V+ pin is bigger than the voltage at the V- pin they output 1 else they output 0.

Life has taught me all things must have a simple answer and it's true to some extent.

I found  some very complicated circuits of comparators on the Internet and I was wondering since for everything there is a simple solution then try to think of one.

Here is my idea:

The comparator is just a simple MOSFET where the output is connected to VCC and drain and the V+ pin is connected to the gate of the MOSFET and the source is connected to the source of the MOSFET.

When the difference between V+ and V- is greater than the threshold voltage of the MOSFET and V+ has bigger voltage than V- it turns on. Also the V+ and V- voltages must be less than the VCC voltage in order for the correct biasing inside the MOSFET.The comparator has some voltage range but it is still useful.

Will it work? [image]

Comment: "What do you think" is not a good question, it sounds like you want an opinion and that is off topic. What kind of answer do you want and to what question? Can you draw that as a schematic, so we don't have to interpret how that would be drawn as a schematic before answering?

Comment: I mean will it work? and currently my computer is being serviced so I can't post any diagram.

Comment: You can simulate if it will work or not in a simulator. Or do some rough calculations by hand. You can also draw the diagram with pen and paper and take a photo.

Comment: A comparator has a very well defined threshold and the output switches fully on the threshold. How will your system compare?

Comment: For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong. -- H. L. Mencken

Comment: Just me I will do just that.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You are still asking what we think and that would result in opinion based answers. Do you have a more specific question about the circuit, other than what we think? Whether it works or not depeds on if it produces the specified output with specified inputs in the specified environment and what those specifications are. Any circuit is really about that, regardless of what we think.

Comment: OK since I have posted the circuit diagram you can tell me if it works since there is only 1 solution for any circuit diagram.

Comment: Yes, it will work... and it is a very good achievement for a newcomer that deserves respect. You have "invented" the simplest MOSFET comparator. I think it would be interesting for you to see  how I "invented" the same but BJT comparator in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/511233/61398… the principle is the same.

Comment: I just finished reading your answer. Good job in inventing the BJT comparator.  Can you upvote please to get 10 points?

Comment: Of course, you deserve it! BTW do you fully understand the role of the resistor here?

Comment: My resistor exists to limit current so there isn't a short circuit.

Comment: Would Einstein turn in his grave if you wanted to dumb down \$E = MC^2\$ just so that you could get to grips with the concept?

Comment: Andy aka I don't get it.

Comment: I also don't get it... but let's get back to the significant circuit concepts. You can remove the resistor and the "comparator" will still work... only its output would be current. But we need voltage as an output. Then?

Comment: Circuit fantasist I agree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your computer is being serviced i thought i just run a quick simulation to show you some issues with your idea.

[image: Schematic for simulation]

[image: Simulation voltage waveforms]

As you can see, the general idea sort of works. If V+ is greater than V- the output voltage drops. However, this is a very crude comparator since a substantial voltage difference between V+ and V- is needed to turn the transistor fully on. As you can see, the output voltage is not very close to 0 V in most cases. But if this is sufficient for your application, i guess you can consider it as a working comparator. On the other hand, you could also just use an op-amp as a comparator.

Comment: Obviously, there is a need of biasing. But how do we bias the MOSFET once both its inputs (gate and source) are occupied? We need a third input to bias it...

Answer (score 0):

More often we start a comparator design with something like this

[Long tailed pair](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512015/long-tailed-pair)

and add transistors on the collectors to produce a LOGIC LEVEL output.