# Long tailed pair

Tags: amplifier, differential-amplifier

How do I  adapt the long tailed pair to fit my requirements?

I've seen circuits where they use 9V Vcc with 10k resistors.
From my understanding the resistors are there to prevent floating base from the transistor.

Should I be working backwards and calculating the current then changing the Vcc to 5V to see the value of resistors I need?

Edit:
Schematic

[image]

Comment: schematic......

Comment: updated with schematic

Comment: What are your *requirements*? It's kind of hard to know how to adapt something to them if we don't know anything about them.

Comment: I would like Vcc, Vin 1 and 2 to be powered by 5V. Also the Vin's have to go through 2 LDRs.

Answer (score 3):

As a start, make those 3 resistors each be 10,000 ohms.

Then add 2 more resistors, from each base to ground, also of value 10,000 ohms.

Make VEE be -9 V, and VDD be +9 V.

What do we expect?

Assuming the bases are near ground (will be slightly below ground), the shared emitter node will be about 0.5 V or 0.6 V or 0.7 V below ground. That makes the voltage across the tail_resistor be 8+ V, the current be 0.8 mA, and if the transistors are matched, you'll have 0.4 mA in each collector.

With 0.4 V in each collector, you'll have 4 V drop across each collector resistor, which makes the collector voltage, measured from Ground, be (9-4) = +5 V.

Now let us check our base voltage. Assuming beta == 100, with 400 uA in each transistor, the base current will be 400/100 = 4 uA.

The voltage drop against the base resistor will be 4 uA * 10,000 ohms.
You can view a 10,000 ohm resistor as 100 uA_per_volt, thus without any math, we already know the voltage is only 40 mV.

If the transistors have Vbe = 0.6 V at 1 mA, given we know 0.018 V is the change for 2:1 or 1:2 change in current, then at 0.4 mA Ic we know the Vbe is (0.6 V - 0.018 - a tiny bit more) or 0.582 V within a few mV.

Comment: "with 0.4 vol in each collector" ? Did you mean: with 0.4mA through each 10k collector resistor?

Comment: Where did "given we know 0.018V is the change for 2:1 or 1:2 change in current" come from?

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding the resistors are there to prevent floating base from the transistor.

The role of the emitter resistor Re is to convert (with the help of transistors) the simultaneously changing ("common-mode") input voltages to collector currents... but this is undesired. So it is a *voltage-to-current converter*.

The role of the collector resistors Rc1 and Rc2 is to convert the collector currents back to voltages. So they are *current-to-voltage converters*.

Answer (score 0):

The process to design a basic long-tailed pair with voltage output is usually as follows:

1. Choose an input common mode voltage - the voltage around which the inputs operate. It must be same for both inputs. The input common mode voltage should be constant when the load is a resistor and not a current source.
2. Choose the operating (tail) current. This depends on the intended speed (slew rate) of the input signals, and on the intended output current range. 1mA is an OK starting point for lower audio frequencies. Slowly changing signals may do fine with 50-100uA. HiFi audio and wideband applications may need several mA.
3. The emitter voltage is the input common mode voltage -0.65V approximately. Choose a tail resistor that will pass the intended tail current at the selected emitter voltage.
4. Determine the minimum collector voltage that keeps the pair operating. For simplicity, you can assume it to be the input common mode voltage, if the input differential voltages are small (<0.3V or so).
5. Choose the output common mode voltage. It should be suitably higher than the minimum collector voltage. You can choose the midpoint of the range between the supply voltage and the minimum collector voltage.
6. Determine the collector load resistors. They should drop VCC-output common mode voltage at 1/2 of the tail current.

The differential voltage gain of the pair is proportional to the tail current \$ I_C \$ and to the value of the collector (load) resistors:

$$A_V \approx {1 \over 2} {I_C \over V_T} R_C,$$

where \$ V_T = 26{\,\rm mV} \$ at room temperature.

For example, at 1mA tail current and 4k7 load resistors, the gain would be about 90.

Higher supply voltages are of advantage, as they let you have same tail current with a larger tail resistance. The higher the tail resistance, the lower the common-mode gain, and thus the better the CMRR (common mode rejection ratio).